# Create AWS IOT thingGroup in Lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-iot

I am Trying to create an IOT thing group in a Lambda function. When I try run this function it just times out and no other errors appear in the logs. Increasing the execution duration does not help.

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    const region = "eu-west-1";
    const iotParams = {"apiVersion": "2019-05-28", "region": region};
    var iot = new AWS.Iot(iotParams);
    var params = {
        thingGroupName: 'test',
        tags: [
            {
                Key: 'name',
                Value: 'test'
            },
            /* more items */
        ],
        thingGroupProperties: {
            attributePayload: {
                attributes: {
                    'name': 'test',
                },
                merge: false
            },
            thingGroupDescription: 'test'
        }
    };
    iot.createThingGroup(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            callback(err);
        }
        else {
            callback(null, data);
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Is the lambda in VPC?

Comment: @Marcin yes it is in a VPC

Comment: I provided some information worth checking when using lambda in vpc.

Answer (score 1):

Common reason for timeouts when using lambda in a VPC is the fact that lambda in VPC **does not have intenet access nor public IP**. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-vpc.html):

> Connect your function to private subnets to access private resources. If your function needs internet access, use NAT. Connecting a function to a public subnet does not give it internet access or a public IP address.

Also the lambda requires special [permissions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-vpc.html#vpc-permissions) in its execution policy:

> ec2:CreateNetworkInterface
>
> ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces
>
> ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface

To access AWS services from lambda in VPC, **NAT gateway** or instance are required. Alternatively, [VPC endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-endpoints.html) can be used for supported services (IoT is not one of them).